# Regex - whitespace or end of string after match c#

Tags: regex

I want to get the a word (A) after a specific word (B) using a regex. But after the B-word there could be some whitespace or the B-word is at the end of the string.

For example:

Two lines:

```
'This is special sentence'
```

and

```
'This is special'
```

With a regex i want to get the word after 'is'. So in the first line the result needs to be 'special', and also in the second line the result needs to be 'special'.

I tried something like:

```
^.*class\ (?<classname>.*)\w.$
```

But with this regex i get 'special' and 'special sentence'.

Comment: can you write a pattern and a example that go together please.

Comment: The regex provided has no relation to the example text you've given (there's no mention of class in your text). Could you update the example text with ones you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)(?<=(is\s))special
```

In your example gets `special` after `is`. You haven't specified a language so this is all I can give. Replace `special` with the word you want to find and `is` with the word that appears before the word you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\bis (\w+)
```

It will capture the word after `is`.

An alternative version with lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bis )(\w+)
```